# Connecting to SQLServer 2005 with adodbapi

Tags: python, database, sql-server-2005, adodbapi

I'm very new to Python and I have Python 3.2 installed on a Win 7-32 workstation. Trying to connect to MSSQLServer 2005 Server using adodbapi-2.4.2.2, the latest update to that package.

The code/connection string looks like this:

***conn = adodbapi.connect('Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=123.456.789');***

From adodbapi I continually get the error (this is entire error message from Wing IDE shell):

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Wing IDE 4.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 2, in 
    if **name** == '**main**':
  File "D:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 298, in connect
    raise InterfaceError #Probably COM Error
adodbapi.adodbapi.InterfaceError:*

I can trace through the code and see the exception as it happens.

I also tried using conn strings with OLEDB provider and integrated Windows security, with same results.

All of these connection strings work fine from a UDL file on my workstation, and from SSMS, but fail with the same error in adodbapi.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know too much about adodbapi, but since it's not working for you maybe give pyodbc a shot. Good luck.

Comment: @Adam - thanks - will try it when they release for Python 3 - on web page they say it's pending - see http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/. I just started with Python about a month ago and python.org recommends that newbies go right to 3 so that's what I have. I would prefer to go ADO direct and not have to bother with ODBC connnections but if that's all I can get to work, I'll go with it. Meanwhile let's see if someone else comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this connection string:

`Initial Catalog=XXX; Data Source=<servername>\\<SQL Instance name>; Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security=SSPI`

### Update

Umm ok. Looking at the source for adodbapi I would have to say that you are suffering a COM error. (yeah I know the traceback says that). But specifically with initialising the relevant COM objects.

This means that your connection string has nothing to do with the traceback. I think a good place to start would be to make sure that your copy of pythoncom is up-to-date.

It could be that win32com/pythoncom does not support Python 3K (3.0 onwards) yet, but after a minute of googleing I have not found anything useful on that, I'll leave it to you.

This code should run successfully when you have fixed your problem (and should fail at the moment).

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
```

Also any exception that code throws would be useful to help debug your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but your conn string using OLEDB didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Mikey Take a quick look at my updated answer and post back the traceback you get.

Comment: will check it out over the weekend.Meanwhile I downgraded Python 2.72 since most of the libraries I want to use aren't P3 ready yet - but still got same error, both with native provider and OLEDB. Right now, the only exception/error message I ever see it what I posted in OP. I'm going to accept your answer because you've taken the time - would appreciate any further help - Tnx.

Comment: @Mikey Ummm ok. When you get the chance a traceback for the test code would be great, but if your having problems when using Python 2.7 then this could be tricky.

Comment: np - I have another machine that I can run with P3

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else finds this thread looking for the resolution to a similar error that I saw with Python 2.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_data.py", line 10, in <module>
    connection = get_connection(r"XXX\YYY", "DB")
  File "get_data.py", line 7, in get_connection
    conn = adodbapi.connect(connstring)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 116, in connect
    raise api.OperationalError(e, message)
adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (InterfaceError("Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.",), 'Error opening connection to "Data Source=XXX\\YYY; Initial Catalog=DB; Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security=SSPI"')
```

In my case the simple solution was to install Python for Windows Extensions (pywin32) from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I tracked it down to a failure to load win32com.pyd, because of some system DLLs that was not in the "dll load path", such as msvcp100.dll

I solved the problem by copying a lot of these dll's (probably too many) into C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2\python-3.3.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\win32

Comment: Thanks - I moved to GoLang a few months ago. Try it... :)