# Unable to perform windows authentication for SQL Server using python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, oledbconnection, adodbapi

My Python code shown below is written to create a SQL Server connection using Windows authentication. I have constraints to use `adodbapi` library for database connectivity.

Please can anyone tell me what is missing from this code? I referred to the library's documentation, but there is nothing mentioning Windows authentication.

I referred to a lot of articles about that exception. But they seems there's no help to understand the nature of exception and its resolution.

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Code:

```
import configparser
import adodbapi
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("C:/plugin/configsql.ini")
_SERVER_NAME = config['SQL']['SERVER_NAME']
_DATABASE = config['SQL']['DATABASE']
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};Integrated Security = True;".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE))
print(conn)
```

Exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Arelle-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 113, in connect
>   co.connect(kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Arelle-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 275, in connect
>   self.connector.Open()  # Open the ADO connection
>
> File "", line 3, in Open
>   File "C:\Arelle-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in *ApplyTypes*
>   result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
>
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Provider', 'Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.', None, 1240640, -2147217887), None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "winAuthentication.py", line 8, in 
>   conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};Integrated Security = True;".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE))
>
> File "C:\Arelle-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 117, in connect
>   raise api.OperationalError(e, message)
>
> adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Provider', 'Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.', None, 1240640, -2147217887), None), 'Error opening connection to "PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=MSSQLSERVER01;Database=TESTDB;Integrated Security = True;"')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Trusted_Connection=yes? Here is my connection string that uses windows authentication (using pyodbc) but should be the same connection parameter, not Integrated Security.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=ServerName;'
                      'Database=DatabaseName;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Or perhaps Integrated Security = SSPI, found mentioned here http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/quick_reference.pdf

```
 'Integrated Security=SSPI'
```

Comment: It doesn't works. It throws exception - `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server', 'Invalid connection string attribute', None, 0, -2147217843), None)`

Comment: Also, you may want to look at these older (but perhaps similar) problems/answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086341/connecting-to-sqlserver-2005-with-adodbapi

Comment: Thanks you. It worked. Updated `'Integrated Security=SSPI'`